# How to build a checkbox list in Angular related to ngModel and other parameters coming from a JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I'm working on Angular. I made a checkbox list with a specific ngModel value for each checkbox.
In order to do that, I built a JSON in my TS component file. The JSON looks like this :

```
  test = [
    {id: 'model1', site: '1', label: 'Clocher', view: 'file_clocher'},
    {id: 'model2', site: '1', label: 'Moulin', view: 'file_moulin'},
    {id: 'model3', site: '1', label: 'Poisson', view: 'file_poisson'},
    {id: 'model4', site: '2', label: 'Lacs', view: 'file_lac'},
    {id: 'model5', site: '2', label: 'Relais', view: 'file_relais'},
    {id: 'model6', site: '3', label: 'Citadelle', view: 'file_citadelle'},
]
```

In the HTML file, here is the following "checkbox code" :

```
<div *ngFor="let j of test">
<div *ngIf="j.site == '1'" class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="j.id" (change)="displayData($event)" name="{{j.view}}"/>
<label class="form-check-label">{{j.label}}</label>
</div>
</div>
```

The `displayData($event)` should allow me to get the `name` parameter of the checkbox checked.
So in my TS file I specified ...

```
displayData(event: any){
  console.log(event.target.name);
}
```

... and the console.log should get e.g "file_clocher" if I check the first checkbox.

But actually I have two problems :

1. All the checkboxes are already checked that is surprising
2. When I check the first checkbox, the console.log returns "undefined" whereas it should return e.g "file_clocher" (chen I try to do it manually, without the JSON, it works)

Would you know how it could be corrected ?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here:
the ngmodel for input is the actual value for that input field, which in the case of a checkbox is boolean. Because j.id is defined, it has a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value which is why they are all checked initially. You probably want another variable defined to track whether those inputs are checked.

you should be able to set the name using `[name]='j.view'` or change the function to just pass in the view name with `(change)="displayData(j.view)"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean that I should not add a ngModel ? If yes, how could I specify when a checkbox has to be unchecked in the TS file (the ngModel helped me to do this).

Comment: You could add another field to your 'j' object like `test = [
    {id: 'model1', site: '1', label: 'Clocher', view: 'file_clocher', value: false}, ...` and then reference it on the input like `[(ngModel)]="j.value"`

Comment: Ok, great it works, all that begins to make sense to me ! A last question if I dare.. is it possible to write in the TS file something like `j.value=false` if I want to uncheck one of the checkboxes using the ngModel ? Thank you again !

Comment: Great! Yeah that's the great thing about [two way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding) in angular is that you can update your models anywhere in code and see the change reflected on the display.

Comment: Great, I will check it and make some tries ! Thank you for the link. If what I will try don't work, could I ask you another question (the last I hope) ? :)

Comment: Ok got it, after many tries, I finally managed to do what I wanted. Thank you very much for your help @justin !!